# Apache Nifi decompression

Tags: apache-nifi, compression

I'm new to Apache NIFI and trying to build a flow as a POC. I need your guidance for the same.

I have a compressed 'gz' file say 'sample.gz' containing a file say 'sample_file'. 
I need to decompress the sample.gz file and store 'sample_file' in a hdfs location.

I'm using GetFile processor to get the sample.gz file, CompressContent processor in decompress mode to decompress the same file and PutHDFS processor to put the decompressed file in HDFS location.

After running the flow, I can find that the original sample.gz file is only copied to HDFS location whereas I needed to copy the sample_file inside the gz file. So decompressing has actually not worked for me.

I hope I could explain the issue I'm facing. Please suggest if I need to change my approach.

Comment: what is the version of nifi do you use?

Answer (score 6):

I used the same sequence of processors but changed  `PutHDFS` to `PutFile`.

```
GetFile --> CompressContent(decompress) --> PutFile
```

In nifi v1.3.0 it works fine.

The only note: if I keep the parameter `Update Filename = false` the for `CompressContent` then the `filename` attribute remains the same after decompression as before (`sample.gz`).

But the content is decompressed.

So, if your question about the filename then:

1. you can change by setting parameter `Update Filename = true` in `CompressContent` processor. in this case `sample.gz` will be changed to `sample` during decompression.
2. use `UpdateAttribute` processor to change the `filename` attribute