# untar tar.gz using Apache-NiFi

Tags: compression, gzip, apache-nifi, tar

I am trying to `untar` `*.tar.gz` folder using Apache-NiFi.

For now, I try to use `GetFile -> CompressContent -> UnpackContent -> PutFile`

In `CompressContent` : `Mode -> Decompress` , `Compress format : gzip`.

**Unable to decompress StandFlowFileContent**

I have referred [this content](http://apache-nifi-users-list.2361937.n4.nabble.com/How-to-untar-quot-tar-gz-quot-file-td585.html), but I dont understand the way they handle flow. Also [this](http://apache-nifi-users-list.2361937.n4.nabble.com/Uncompressing-nested-tar-tar-gz-gz-and-zip-files-td2211.html) and this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44652827/apache-nifi-decompression).

Unzipping `.zip` was success.

Error in `nifi.app.log`

> ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-4]
>   o.a.n.p.standard.CompressContent
>   CompressContent[id=2de4b824-0170-1000-d04c-74134b40ca19] Unable to
>   decompress
>   StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=0b92f803-8841-42d2-b2c5-8efe16206485,claim=StandardContentClaim
>   [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1581349027084-1,
>   container=default, section=1], offset=176,
>   length=176],offset=0,name=data.tar.xz,size=176] using gzip compression
>   format due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException:
>   IOException thrown from
>   CompressContent[id=2de4b824-0170-1000-d04c-74134b40ca19]:
>   java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Input is not in the .gz
>   format; routing to failure:
>   org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: IOException
>   thrown from CompressContent[id=2de4b824-0170-1000-d04c-74134b40ca19]:
>   java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Input is not in the .gz
>   format

Error is true, as I am using a `tar.gz` file.

Comment: Which error did you get ?

Comment: @maximeG Unable to decompress StandFlowFileContent

Comment: Did you try uncompress 2 times, with both gzip ?
The first uncompress should give you *.tar and the seconde one the files. can you look at the queue ?

Comment: @maximeG uncompress using `UnpackContent`? or `CompressContnet -> gzip`?

Comment: first use compressContent with decompress mode gzip then use unpackContent with tar format.

Comment: @maximeG Yes, I have the same flow. But I get same error **Unable to decompress StandFlowFileContent**.

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram, please edit your question and provide the full stacktrace from the log file for "Unable to decompress" error message

Comment: @daggett added error log. it says file is not `.gz`, I use a `*.tar.gz`

Comment: So the incoming file is not a gzip file even it has the `.gz` extension

Comment: @daggett yes, it was with `tar` file format. Now its working, but still I get **IOException thrown from UnpackContent: java.io.IOException: Error detected parsing the header**